# Gravity not being applied to character, using character controller

Tags: unity, c#

So I just copy and pasted the unity example class to use with my character controller.

```
public float speed = 6.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
void Update() {
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

The code seems to work okay if I comment out the isGrounded check statement (which means that gravity isn't being applied). So what could be the reason that the gravity is not being applied to my character controller?

Comment: Code has very little effect on Gravity. Can you post screenshot of your character in inespector? Please post screenshot showing settings of character only.

Comment: check the code that sets "controller.isGrounded"

Comment: From the way your script looks, gravity is applied regardless of the state of controller.isGrounded

Answer (score 1):

It looks like time scaling could be an issue here: you scale gravity by Time.deltaTime and apply that to the y axis of the movement vector. You then take that vector and scale it by Time.deltaTime.

This means that the y axis has been scaled twice. Given that there is usually very little time between Updates, you'll probably find that this means moveDirection.y is an infinismall number which gets rounded out to 0.